# Hide button with jQuery after submit Account

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to hide one **submit button** when ***#email*** and customer **#first/lastname** have value (is successfully saved) #submitAccount to be hidden.

Working code:

```
                {literal}
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                            $("#submitGuestAccount").click(function () {
                             if($("#email").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_firstname").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_lastname").val().trim().length>0 )   {
                                    $('#new_account_form p.submit').hide();
                                }
                            });
                });
            </script>
            {/literal}
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="exclusive button" name="submitAccount" id="submitAccount" value="{l s='Save'}" />
            </p>
```

But how to add filter - When page is load and

```
  if($("#email").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_firstname").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_lastname").val().trim().length>0 )
```

Again button to be hidden. Now when i refresh page button shows again?

Comment: You are missing a `});` to close ready()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition to

```
if($("#email").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_firstname").val().trim().length>0 && $("#customer_lastname").val().trim().length>0 )   {
    $('#submitAccount').hide();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great, that work! But i choice other selectors because page is checkout and i use guest account. But now i have other problem. This code work fine but: When i reload page or go to other page and get back to checkout (this page with button) button is there. How to add filter that to check when page is loaded?

Comment: Are you having `pageinit` functions? If so, you can set a flag to true in `pageinit` for that particular page. And check in `pagebeforeshow` @user3388282

Comment: I Searching about "pageinit" function but i can`t find it anywhere in shop files.

Comment: Is that a jquery mobile app? If so, here is [pageinit](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/). Else you can keep a boolean variable initially false, and make it true after hiding button for first time.

Comment: No, is not mobile app. It`s prestashop but nowhere i can find function "pageinit" or may be i don`t know where to search - i search in several js - that checkout page using but there no "pageinit"

How to add it?

Answer (score 0):

Please close the ready by adding `});`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submitAccount").click(function () {
                if ($("#email").val() && $("#customer_firstname").val() && $("#customer_lastname").val()) {
                    $('#submitAccount').hide();
                }
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#submitAccount").click(function () {
                    if ($("#email").val() && $("#customer_firstname").val() && $("#customer_lastname").val()) {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                }); 
    </script>

    <p class = "submit"> <input type = "submit" class="exclusive button" name="submitAccount" id = "submitAccount" value = "{l s='Save'}"/></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Mathias is right.. you are missing the closing of the ready function..
 sometimes I use the simple known trick to see if my code is buggy.. which is adding the alert method

e.g. add

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submitAccount").click(function () {
                if ($("#email").val() && $("#customer_firstname").val() && $("#customer_lastname").val()) {
                    $('#submitAccount').hide();
alert('after the hiding method');
                }
}
            });
```

when that alert method is not invoked then your code is missing something